# .NET Core / EF Core Linq - get entities with certain level of nesting

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have these 3 models:

- MainModel -> contains a collection of ModelA and a collection of ModelB.
- ModelA -> contains a collection of ModelA and a collection of ModelB.
- ModelB -> contains a collection of ModelA and a collection of ModelB.

So they can be nested at infinite levels (example, a `MainModel` that contains 1 or more `ModelA`, and any of those contains another `ModelA` or a `ModelB`, and any of those contains another `ModelA` or `ModelB` etc...).

```
public class MainModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // nav. props
    public virtual ICollection<ModelA> ModelsA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ModelB> ModelsB { get; set; }
}

public class ModelA 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("ParentMainModel")]
    public int? IdParentMainModel { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentModelA")]
    public int? IdParentModelA { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentModelB")]
    public int? IdParentModelB { get; set; }

    //nav.props
    public virtual ModelA ParentModelA { get; set; }
    public virtual ModelB ParentModelB { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ModelA> ModelsA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ModelB> ModelsB { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("ParentMainModel")]
    public int? IdParentMainModel { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentModelA")]
    public int? IdParentModelA { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentModelB")]
    public int? IdParentModelB { get; set; }

    //nav.props
    public virtual ModelA ParentModelA { get; set; }
    public virtual ModelB ParentModelB { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ModelA> ModelsA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ModelB> ModelsB { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get all `MainModel`s from the database that contain `ElementsA` and/or `elementsB` with for example 4 levels of nesting...

Can this be done with EF Core using linq?

Comment: It is possible with Recursive CTE. CTE not supported by EF Core, but this part can be done by `FromSql`. Which EF Core version do you use?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I am using EF Core v6.0.23

Comment: Can you supply with test data. Here i see three ways of nesting. How `IdParentMainModel` is set?  I have prepared small sample but I cannot understand how to create real data.

Answer (score 0):

This Recursive CTE should return MainModel classes which has child items with desired level:

```cs
var level = 4;

var query = context.MainModels.FromSqlRaw(@"
    WITH [cte]
    (
        [MainId],
        [Level],
        [AId],
        [BId]
    )
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            [it].[MainId],
            1,
            [it].[AId],
            [it].[BId]
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    [a].[IdParentMainModel] as [MainId],
                    [a].[Id] as [AId],
                    NULL as [BId]
                FROM
                    [ModelsA] [a]
                WHERE
                    [a].[IdParentMainModel] IS NOT NULL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    [b].[IdParentMainModel] as [MainId],
                    NULL as [AId],
                    [b].[Id] as [BId]
                FROM
                    [ModelsB] [b]
                WHERE
                    [b].[IdParentMainModel] IS NOT NULL
            ) [it]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            [c_1].[MainId],
            [c_1].[Level] + 1,
            [a_1].[Id],
            NULL
        FROM
            [cte] [c_1]
                INNER JOIN [ModelsA] [a_1] ON [a_1].[IdParentModelA] = [c_1].[AId]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            [c_2].[MainId],
            [c_2].[Level] + 1,
            NULL,
            [b_1].[Id]
        FROM
            [cte] [c_2]
                INNER JOIN [ModelsB] [b_1] ON [b_1].[IdParentModelB] = [c_2].[BId]
    )
    SELECT
        [m_1].*
    FROM
        [MainModels] [m_1]
    WHERE
        EXISTS(
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                [cte] [c_3]
            WHERE
                [c_3].[MainId] = [m_1].[Id] AND [c_3].[Level] = {0}
        )
    ", level);
            
    var result = query.ToList();
```

Note that this query is non-composable. It can only return result.

---

For generating this query i have used third party library [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (note that I'm one of the creators)
It was simplier to debug and compose such CTE:

```cs
using var db = context.CreateLinqToDBConnection();

var items =
    (
        from a in context.ModelsA
        where a.IdParentMainModel != null
        select new
        {
            MainId = a.IdParentMainModel.Value,
            AId = (int?)a.Id,
            BId = (int?)null
        })
    .Concat(
        from b in context.ModelsB
        where b.IdParentMainModel != null
        select new
        {
            MainId = b.IdParentMainModel.Value,
            AId = (int?)null,
            BId = (int?)b.Id
        });

var cteQuery = db.GetCte<CteModel>(cte =>
    (
        from it in items
        select new CteModel
        {
            MainId = it.MainId,
            AId = it.AId,
            BId = it.BId,
            Level = 1
        }
    )
    .Concat(
        from c in cte
        from a in context.ModelsA.Where(a => a.IdParentModelA == Sql.AsNotNull(c.AId))
        select new CteModel
        {
            MainId = c.MainId,
            AId = a.Id,
            Level = c.Level + 1
        })
    .Concat(
        from c in cte
        from b in context.ModelsB.Where(b => b.IdParentModelB == Sql.AsNotNull(c.BId))
        select new CteModel
        {
            MainId = c.MainId,
            BId = b.Id,

            Level = c.Level + 1
        })
);

var level = 4;

var resultQuery =
    from m in context.MainModels.ToLinqToDB()
    where cteQuery.Any(c => c.MainId == m.Id && c.Level == level)
    select m;

var result = resultQuery.ToArray();
```

Helper class

```cs
class CteModel
{
    public int MainId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int? AId { get; set; }
    public int? BId { get; set; }
}
```